# Lp Space: an intuitive understanding.

Tags: analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

Would someone be willing to give me an intuitive understanding of the Lp space? I have several analysis books which (seemingly) approach the topic differently, which confuses me more, and a simple Google search hasn't led me to any greater enlightenment either. I would be grateful for any feedback from the community.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When I was learning this I considered them as motivated from the standard $p$-series in elementary calculus (used for comparison and limit comparison tests) and the corresponding $x^p$ growth rates used for determining convergence/divergence of improper integrals (use $\int_1^{\infty}x^p\,dx$ for comparison with infinite integrand integrals, use $\int_0^1 x^p\,dx$ for comparison when integrating across places where the function values are unbounded at a point). However, this is probably more along the lines of "how does this relate to something you've studied before" than what you're asking.

Comment: Yes, I am looking for something along the lines, 'this is what Lp spaces are in a primitive or classical sense' rather than a comparison. Still, I am grateful for your comment.

Comment: *with infinite integrand integrals* --- This doesn't say what I intended, since "infinite integrand" (to me at least) suggests we're talking about input values where the integrand function blows up. What I meant was when one (or both) of the limits of integration is infinite. **Regarding your question,** maybe see beginning on p. 54 of [The development of function Spaces with particular reference to their origins in integral equation theory](https://www.jstor.org/stable/41133253) by Michael Bernkopf.

Comment: Thanks for the resource. I read the page you recommend. It still defies my understanding. Is there a very basic classical problem that motivated the origin of Lp spaces? -For example, on page 54, the paper reads, "These discoveries stem from his interest in generalizing the moment problem presented in his first 1907 paper...", but I am not a physicist; I have no idea what that means.

Comment: Another such paper is [*The establishment of functional analysis*](http://math.gmu.edu/~rsachs/math675/History%20Functional%20Analysis.pdf) by Garrett Birkhoff and Erwin Kreyszig. Although probably at least as dense as the other paper, Frigyes Riesz's introduction of these spaces is discussed on p. 287. Riesz established a connection between the sequence of coefficients of certain generalized Fourier series expansions and square-integrable functions. The sequence of coefficients is viewed as a point in a certain infinite-dimensional space -- use the usual Pythagorean theorem type of formula,

Comment: but have infinitely many coordinates, so need the sequence to be in $\ell^2.$ Roughly speaking, as people studied these spaces (the generalization from exponent $2$ to exponent $p>0$ was a natural thing to consider), a huge number of connections with other things were found and new areas of research opened up. Maybe from your point of view (which is not at all the same as those working on this stuff back then) just view these as "nice collections" of functions.

Comment: For $p=1$ you have (finitely) integrable functions, for $p=5$ (say) you have functions that are $5$-th power (finitely) integrable. Most of the examples and counterexamples for $E = [0,1]$ and $E = [1,\infty)$ and similar sets can be obtained by using elementary calculus improper integral examples. The collections are nice because they are closed under addition of functions, and there is a natural "distance" between two functions (not how far apart their graphs are vertically separated --- that's the "sup" metric) that gives geometric insight into many seemingly purely analytic situations.

Comment: Ahh yes! Thank-you; this is quite helpful. I better understand your previous comments now.

Answer (score 6):

I like to look at $L_p$ spaces like generalizations of Euclidean spaces. You can imagine them like Euclidean spaces, but with vectors having infinite number of coordinates. Here the "vectors" are not finite, like ($x_1$, $x_3$, $x_3$, ... $x_n$), but infinite. In the discrete case (small $l_p$ spaces), which is simpler to visualize, the "vectors" have "coordinates" ($x_1$, $x_3$, $x_3$, ... $x_n$, $x_{n+1}$, $x_{n+2}$...) - its coordinates form infinite sequences.
In the continuous case ($L_p$ spaces), the "coordinates" are not separate for each n, but their domain is continuous - of course, since $L_p$ are function spaces.

$L_p$ spaces are important for studying properties and interactions of functions that live there.
Just as vector quantities live in vector spaces, functions f: X $\to$ ${\Bbb C}$ live in function spaces $L_p$. This space also provides some strucutre for the world where functions live. It has a structure of vector space, some algebraic structure (we can multiply functions), metric structure (we can tell if two functions in $L_p$ are "close" or "apart"), topological structure (useful for studying various kind of convergence), norm structure (distinguishing "large" functions from "small" ones) etc.